# Best practice sending HTTP GET requests

Tags: java, http-get

Is there better practice for sending HTTP GET requests than the following?

```
    private StringBuffer getData(String url)  throws Exception
{
        URL obj; 

        obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();         
        return response;
}
```

Comment: maybe Webclient.DownloadString?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the two simple changes you should make are to close your input stream in a `finally` block, and use a `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`.

Furthermore, you may want to check the response code and throw an exception if you receive an error response (400+, 500+, etc).

Edit:

If you are planning on buffering all of the content anyways, and you do not mind using libraries, then you can simply do:

```
Request.Get("http://some.url").execute().returnContent();
```

Using [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/index.html).

Comment: very cool! yes, the apache components is what I was looking for regarding a comparison in practice. thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 4):

```
String uri = "your url";
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    String responseStr = buildResponseFromEntity(response.getEntity());

    private String buildResponseFromEntity(HttpEntity entity)
                throws IllegalStateException, IOException {

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    entity.getContent()));
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
            return total.toString();
            }
    // check if error
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            JSONObject jsonObj = null;
            try {
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(responseStr);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // do your code
            }
}
```

Comment: You may want to mention that this is using Apache HttpComponents for clarity.  Additionally, I believe that it is still best practices to use a finally block and call `httpGet.releaseConnection()` to release the underlying connection.  This work can also all be saved if the content is being buffered anyways by just using `Request.Get("http://some.url").execute().returnContent();`